# MPLAB 8.92 checksum missing on release build

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, pic, mplab, pic32

I'm getting a PIC32MX project ready for programming at the fab house and I was hoping to send a checksum along with the .hex file for them to be able to verify the .hex at their end.

If I compile the program in a debug configuration MPLAB 8.92 shows the usual checksum once complete, If I select release configuration the checksum shows only 0x0000.

Is there a way to force MPLAB to show me the checksum? Alternatively is there any program I can download and run my hex through for the checksum?

nodee

Comment: Hex files (as well as s-record files) don't use CRC, but a naive, amateur-level checksum. It is calculated by adding all the byte values together, grab the ls byte, then invert it. I believe Intel inverts it as two's complement (while Motorola s-records inverts it as bit-wise complement). Not really a hard program to write yourself.

Comment: I think most tools and programmers don't use the checksum because it's such a shitty one by design, with a very high probability of failing. Instead, programming is/should be verified by reading back the programmed data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found using the new Mplab IPE checksum feature to be a great Production checksum. Mostly because our Fab house programs using it so they see the checksum in the utility just as I do when putting it into our documentation.

[image: IPE]